# Trying to Mock Network Calls in Xcode UI Testing

Tags: swift, mocking, afnetworking, xcode-ui-testing

I have an existing ios application that needs UI tests. I have tried a number of existing libraries and so far everything has been a dead end. The only solutions I have seen thus far involve adding test specific functions to the production code and enabling/disabling them with launch arguments.

Does anyone know of a good way to mock out back-end network calls without polluting my production code with test logic?

So far I have tried:

[NSURLSession-MOCK](https://github.com/net-a-porter-mobile/NSURLSession-Mock)

-Relies on swizzling, which has no effect in UI tests.

[OHTTPStubs](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs)

-Does not allow upload (PUSH, PUT) requests to be mocked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock data in UITest on Xcode 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403684/how-to-mock-data-in-uitest-on-xcode-7)

Comment: Updated my question. I want a solution that doesn't require adding test-only logic to my production code.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible given the current state of Xcode UI Testing (Xcode 7.3 Beta 4).

Comment: @pbuchheit please read my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38086478/25077

Comment: Seems like an interesting solution. If I get the chance I will try it out and see if it meets our needs.